# Git Authentication failed in Linux when credentials provided in the URL

Tags: linux, git, authentication, azure-devops

I trying to clone Git repository  (from TFS/Azure, but I don't think it's important).
I have to use the HTTP method, so I use the following format:
https://**username:password**@corptfs.com/tfs/CorpCollection/MyProject

This fails with the "Authentication failed" Error.
It works fine under windows (we have the same code running in Windows Agents.)

What is even more strange: it works if I provide the credentials manually (using only the URL, and user/pass are entered when asked by the prompt).

It also works if I use this format:  https://**username**@corptfs.com/tfs/CorpCollection/MyProject
and provide the Password only at the prompt.

Comment: Are there special characters like `@` in the username or password?

Comment: nope. only letters (lower and upper case) and numbers.

Comment: there is "_" in the username

Comment: Have you tried quoting the URL on the command line? `git clone 'https://username:password@...'`

Comment: @larsks yes, no luck